# Placement new base subobject of derived in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, strict-aliasing, object-lifetime, placement-new

Is it defined behavior to placement-new a trivially destructible base object of a derived?

```
struct base { int& ref; };
struct derived : public base {
    complicated_object complicated;
    derived(int& r, complicated_arg arg) :
            base {r}, complicated(arg) {}
};

unique_ptr<derived> rebind_ref(unique_ptr<derived>&& ptr,
                               int& ref) {
    // Change where the `ref` in the `base` subobject of
    // derived refers.
    return unique_ptr<derived>(static_cast<derived*>(
        ::new (static_cast<base*>(ptr.release()) base{ref}));
}
```

Note that I tried to structure `rebind_ref` to not break any strict aliasing assumptions a compiler might have made.

Comment: why not use `int *ref` in this case. derived class may be written assuming that ref never changes.

Comment: My question is not about rebinding a reference. It is about constructing a "new" value on top of the base subobject of a derived.

Comment: Reusing memory ends the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not allowed by the C++ Standard, for at least two reasons.

The text that sometimes allows a placement-new of a new object into the storage for another object of the same type is found in [[basic.life], paragraph 8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8).  The bold emphasis is mine.

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, **does not contain any non-static data member whose type is** const-qualified or **a reference type**, and
> - [C++17] the original object was a **most derived object** of type `T` and the new object is a most derived object of type `T` (that is, they are **not base class subobjects**).
> - [C++20 draft 2018-10-09] **neither the original object nor the new object is a potentially-overlapping subobject** ([intro.object]).

The C++20 change is to account for the possibility of zero-size non-static data members, but it still also rules out all base class subobjects (empty or not). "Potentially-overlapping subobject" is a new term defined in [[intro.object] paragraph 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7):

> A *potentially-overlapping subobject* is either:
>
> - **a base class subobject**, or
> - a non-static data member declared with the `no_unique_address` attribute ([dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr]).

(Even if you do find some way to rearrange things to avoid the reference member and base class issues, remember to make sure nobody can ever define a `const derived` variable, for example by making all constructors private!)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. "...a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object..." is interesting. Is the result of a placement-new expression a "pointer that pointed to the original object", or a pointer to the newly constructed object (despite it occupying the same memory location)?

Comment: The result of any new-expression, including placement new, points at the created object.  That sentence is talking about previously existing pointers and references.

Comment: I carefully structured `rebind_ref` so that it consumes the "old" pointer and returns the "new" pointer that is the result of the placement-new expression `static_cast`ed to `derived`. Is this sufficient to avoid the "pointer that pointed to the original object" rule?

Comment: @Filipp A base class subobject isn't really a "pointer", "reference", or "name".  But the Standard doesn't need to clarify how a derived object behaves after replacing a base class subobject, because it says such a replacement is always invalid in the first place.

Comment: Actually, the sections of the standard you quoted above only speak whether a "pointer", "reference", or "name" that referred to the object that previously occupied some storage can be used to manipulate the new object created there. In C++17 I'd use `std::launder` to "create" a "new name". Unfortunately, I only have access to C++14. Does placement new have `std::launder` powers before C++17?

Answer (score -1):

```
static_cast<derived*>(
        ::new (&something) base{ref})
```

is not valid, by definition `new (...) base(...)` creates a `base` object as a new complete object, that can be considered an existing complete object or  **member** subobject sometimes (under conditions that aren't met by `base` anyway) but never a base subobject.

**There is no existing rule** that says you can pretend `new (addr) base` creates a valid derived object just because the `base` object is overwriting another `base` base subobject. If there previously was a `derived` object, you have just reused its storage with  `new (addr) base`. Even if by some magic the `derived` object was still in existence, the result of the evaluation of the new expression wouldn't point to it, it would point to a `base` complete object.

If you want to pretend you did something (like creating a `derived` object), without actually doing it (calling a `derived` constructor), you can pour some `volatile` qualifiers on pointers to force the compiler to erase all assumptions on values and compile the code as if there was an ABI transition.

Comment: Where would you recommend that I add `volatile` qualifiers to make what I'm doing not UB without negatively affecting how a compiler can optimize this code?

Comment: @Filipp The goal of `volatile` is to remove information from the compiler: the value of a `volatile` object seems to be coming from a separately compiled unit (and possibly a different compiler and language). **The standard doesn't cover at all separate compilation or mixing different languages, not even C.**